# PowerShell 2.0 script to extract json data

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

**UPDATE** - The Solution was very simple with Powershell 5.1. I posted an answer separately"

I am attempting my first Powershell script (version 2.0 in Windows 7). I am reading the following json text from a file (that part works). I want to get the value of "public_url". The error I'm getting with the script below is"

```
Select-Object : Property "tunnels" cannot be found
```

Being my first time using Powershell, I don't quite have the grasp of how to navigate objects. Thanks in advance,

**My json file contents:**

```
  {
     "tunnels":[
        {
           "name":"command_line",
           "uri":"/api/tunnels/command_line",
           "public_url":"tcp://8.tcp.ngrok.io:12716",
           "proto":"tcp",
           "config":{
              "addr":"localhost:32400",
              "inspect":false
           },
           "metrics":{
              "conns":{
                 "count":0,
                 "gauge":0,
                 "rate1":0,
                 "rate5":0,
                 "rate15":0,
                 "p50":0,
                 "p90":0,
                 "p95":0,
                 "p99":0
              },
              "http":{
                 "count":0,
                 "rate1":0,
                 "rate5":0,
                 "rate15":0,
                 "p50":0,
                 "p90":0,
                 "p95":0,
                 "p99":0
              }
           }
        }
     ],
     "uri":"/api/tunnels"
  }
```

**My Powershell Script:**

```
function ConvertFrom-Json20([object] $item){ 
  add-type -assembly system.web.extensions
  $ps_js=new-object system.web.script.serialization.javascriptSerializer

  #The comma operator is the array construction operator in PowerShell
  return ,$ps_js.DeserializeObject($item)
}

$content = get-content -path "c:\path\to\json.txt"
$json = ConvertFrom-Json20($content)

$url = $json | select -expand tunnels | select public_url

echo "url=>" $url
```

Comment: New to PS, on WIn7, if this is your personal machine, why not just upgrade to PS5x, which is the last version of `Windows Powershell`? MS has stated that is the last version, but it will be in all future OS versions for the foreseeable future, just as cmd.exe is. The cross-platform PowerShell Core (currently v7), is the future, and regularly updated. What Windows PowerShell is today, is what it will be forever. PowerShell Core is not an upgrade or replacement of Windows PowerShell. It is a side-by-side install on Windows, that also works on Linux and OSX and it is M365/Azure uses.

Comment: WInPS relies on the full Windows .Net platform, PowerShell Core only uses .Net Core. WinPSv5/PSCore already has built-in JSON cmdlets. So, don't stress yourself out on legacy PS that is no longer supported and really should be disabled on systems.

Comment: I'm happy to upgrade to PS5x. It is my understanding that the function `ConvertFrom-Json20` was a polyfill so I'd be dealing with the same object in the end. Correct? So, should `url = $json | select -expand tunnels | select public_url` work with PS5x?

Comment: Being new is fine, but you should really spend the time getting up to speed on PowerShell as a whole first. Youtube is your friend. [Beginning PowerShell](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=beginning+PowerShell) as for Powershell using JSON, or other, [Youtube is still prudent](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=PowerShell+JSON).

Comment: See my update for you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice to upgrade to PS 5.1. Made all the difference. I can see my objects now and things just work.

Comment: For what it is worth, even the `-ExpandProperty` parameter is quiet outdated and mainly replaced by [member enumeration](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/new-v3-language-features/) since PowerShell version 3.

Comment: All it took with PS5.1 was the following: `$json = get-content -path "e:\downloads\ngrok\ngrokURL.txt" | ConvertFrom-Json
$url = $json.tunnels.public_url`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comments.
Just upgrade to the latest WinPS use the JSON cmdlets, don't try and reinvent the wheel.

Windows Management Framework 5.1

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616

> Windows Management Framework 5.1 includes updates to Windows
> PowerShell, Windows PowerShell Desired State Configuration (DSC),
> Windows Remote Management (WinRM), Windows Management Instrumentation
> (WMI). Release notes: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=839460

```
Get-Command -Name '*json*' | Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
CommandType Name             Version Source                      
----------- ----             ------- ------                      
Cmdlet      ConvertFrom-Json 3.1.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
Cmdlet      ConvertTo-Json   3.1.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
#>
```

PowerShell natively uses JSON, XML and you have access to all of .Net, so, you can use the .Net namespaces for JSON.

Just look at the help files on how to use them. There are full explanations and examples.

```
# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Get-Help).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Get-Help).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Get-Help -Examples
Get-help -Name Get-Help -Full
Get-help -Name Get-Help -Online


(Get-Command -Name ConvertFrom-Json).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name ConvertFrom-Json).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name ConvertFrom-Json -Examples
Get-help -Name ConvertFrom-Json -Full
Get-help -Name ConvertFrom-Json -Online


(Get-Command -Name ConvertTo-Json).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name ConvertTo-Json).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name ConvertTo-Json -Examples
Get-help -Name ConvertTo-Json -Full
Get-help -Name ConvertTo-Json -Online
```

***Update as per your comment***

Using the above, you can just navigate JSON object, by dot reference and or index.

```
$JsonData = '
{
     "tunnels":[
        {
           "name":"command_line",
           "uri":"/api/tunnels/command_line",
           "public_url":"tcp://8.tcp.ngrok.io:12716",
           "proto":"tcp",
           "config":{
              "addr":"localhost:32400",
              "inspect":false
           },
           "metrics":{
              "conns":{
                 "count":0,
                 "gauge":0,
                 "rate1":0,
                 "rate5":0,
                 "rate15":0,
                 "p50":0,
                 "p90":0,
                 "p95":0,
                 "p99":0
              },
              "http":{
                 "count":0,
                 "rate1":0,
                 "rate5":0,
                 "rate15":0,
                 "p50":0,
                 "p90":0,
                 "p95":0,
                 "p99":0
              }
           }
        }
     ],
     "uri":"/api/tunnels"
  }
' | 
ConvertFrom-Json

$JsonData
# Results
<#
tunnels                                                                                                                    uri         
-------                                                                                                                    ---         
{@{name=command_line; uri=/api/tunnels/command_line; public_url=tcp://8.tcp.ngrok.io:12716; proto=tcp; config=; metrics=}} /api/tunnels
#>

$JsonData.tunnels
# Results
<#
name       : command_line
uri        : /api/tunnels/command_line
public_url : tcp://8.tcp.ngrok.io:12716
proto      : tcp
config     : @{addr=localhost:32400; inspect=False}
metrics    : @{conns=; http=}
#>

$JsonData.uri
# Results
<#
/api/tunnels
#>

$JsonData.uri.Split('/')
# Results
<#
api
tunnels
#>

$JsonData.uri.Split('/')[-1]
# Results
<#
tunnels
#>
```

As for your stuff... Well, it's never an object. just a string.

This does not work as you'd think

```
function ConvertFrom-Json20([object] $item)
{ 
  Add-Type -Assembly System.Web.Extensions

  $ps_js = New-Object System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavascriptSerializer
  return
  $ps_js.DeserializeObject($item)
}

($content = Get-Content -path 'D:\Scripts\json.txt')

($json = ConvertFrom-Json20($content))
# Results
<#
Nothing is returned
#>

# So this would never work
# Results
<#
$url = $json | select -expand tunnels | select public_url

echo "url=>" $url
#>
```

So, just read the data and grab the string

```
(Get-Content -path 'D:\Scripts\json.txt').Trim() | 
Select-String -Pattern 'uri.*'
# Results
<#
"uri":"/api/tunnels/command_line",
"uri":"/api/tunnels"
#>

((Get-Content -path 'D:\Scripts\json.txt').Trim() | 
Select-String -Pattern 'uri.*')[-1] -replace '"' -split('/')
# Results
<#
uri:
api
tunnels
#>
(((Get-Content -path 'D:\Scripts\json.txt').Trim() | 
Select-String -Pattern 'uri.*')[-1] -replace '"' -split('/'))[-1]
# Results
<#
tunnels
#>
```

To get an object from that JSON file, in PSv2, you'd say do something like this.

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Web.Extensions')

$JsonData    = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Scripts\Json.txt'
$Serializer  = New-Object System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
($JsonObject = $Serializer.DeserializeObject($JsonData))
# Results
<#
Key     Value                                                                 
---     -----                                                                 
tunnels {System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]}
uri     /api/tunnels 
#>
```

Or this way...

```
($JsonObject = New-Object PSObject -Property $Serializer.DeserializeObject($JsonData))
# Results
<#
tunnels                                                                uri         
-------                                                                ---         
{System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]} /api/tunnels
#>
```

... then dot reference

```
$JsonObject.tunnels
# Results
<#
Key        Value
---        -----
name       command_line
uri        /api/tunnels/command_line
public_url tcp://8.tcp.ngrok.io:12716 
proto      tcp
config     {[addr, localhost:32400], [inspect, False]}
metrics    {[conns, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary
#>

$JsonObject.uri
# Results
<#
/api/tunnels
#>
```

Comment: That was pretty simple once I had access to the dot reference. Thank you - that saved a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple answer with Powershell 5.1

```
$json = get-content -path "c:\path\to\json.txt" | ConvertFrom-Json
$url = $json.tunnels.public_url
```